# Converting a lead using publisher action

Tags: publisher-action

I am using a publisher action to convert a lead.
My Visualforce Page looks like this:

```
 <apex:page standardController="Lead" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
<apex:commandLink action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Convert, lead.id, [retURL=$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL, nooppti=1], true)}" value="Convert" target="_parent"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Before I convert the lead, I need to update 1 field on the lead object. Is it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: One simple solution would be to link the update action with a visual flow.

Comment: If you're comfortable with code, a trigger would work fine, or you could write an extension to update the lead before taking them on to the convert page.

Comment: I am not too comfortable with code, but I am learning. Do you have any hints how I can get started? So, I assume I create an extension on that vf page above. And in that extension I set my field to the required value. ...and how do I do that, so that it then goes on to convert the lead? tia.

Comment: @crmprogdev - I am just checking the Visual Flow designer, and I cannot see where the update action for convert lead is? How would I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: In the flow palette, if you scroll all the way down, you should see quick actions and static actions.

Comment: @crmprogdev - yes, I can see that, but I cannot see any actions that would convert a lead? Is it possible to link a visual flow to a button and then when clicking the button, I invoke the flow and create a new account and new contact from there? I can see those actions!

Comment: I'm not certain I can answer all your questions for your use case. You may need to recreate your action from within Flow designer. Yes, you can invoke the flow from a button. You may want to review the video you see when you open Flow Designer and the many other flow training resources available from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs as references.